# prove that $F(x)$ satisfy $F(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda F(x)+(1-\lambda)F(y)$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ satisfy $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$ on $[0,+\infty)$,where $\lambda \in (0,1)$, note $$ F(x)=\frac{\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt}{x}$$,show that
$$F(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda F(x)+(1-\lambda)F(y)$$
holds in $(0,+\infty)$

I think we can prove the $f$ is continuous,therefore,just show that $F'(x)$ is increase function,and it's suffice to prove
$$ \left(\frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{f(y)}{y} \right)\leq \frac{\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt}{x^2}-\frac{\int_{0}^{y}f(t)dt}{y^2}$$ for$x>y$, but I stuck here...

Comment: Have you heard about convexity of a function? That it is sufficient that $f''(x)\geqslant 0$ for convexity to hold?

Comment: You need to state the context and what you know, otherwise we can't help you.  Furthermore, what are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @IanMateus no one said this function has two derivatives.  I believe convex functions are almost everywhere differentiable, but that is the most you can assume.

Comment: @BettyMock true, googling gives many counterexamples. I didn't see that.

Comment: @pxchg1200 I don't think showing F' > 0 helps anything -- you are tring to show F is convex.  I suggest you plug  $\lambda x + (1 - \lambda y$) into your integral.  I think it will all work out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
F(x) = \int_0^1 f(tx)dt
$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}
\lambda F(x) + (1-\lambda)F(y) &= \int_0^1 [\lambda f(tx) + (1-\lambda)f(ty)]dt \\&\geq \int_0^1 f(\lambda tx + (1-\lambda)ty)dt \\&= F(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)
\end{align}$$